# Ios transfer app from one account to other account when in status "Preparing for Submission"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Whether i can do transfer app account when my app status is in "Preparing for submission"..?

2 build versions are present in my account
one is ready for sale(1.0.3) i.e available in apple store
another which i created recently and in status "Preparing for submission"

i am not able to see that option/link in itunesconnect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can only transfer application which have "Ready for Sale" status.

So you do have 2 options:

1. Submit current application, when its Ready for Sale, you will have an option to transfer the application
2. You can remove current application from the iTunesConnect and then create new application and submit to the app store via another apple account.

Note: In above both the cases, Application and Application Identifier will be transfer to the new account, rest all the things - Certificates, Provision Profiles, Device List, App Groups - has to create in new account when to prepare new build and release to the app store.

Reference: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devaf27784ff

Comment: Thank you for the reply..
one more thing i want know here is
after transfer of account if i want to upload a new build with new account(Meaning recipients Account) then i need to create all distribution certificate and all again..?,

Comment: Can you please approve the answer by up voting it, it would be great.

Comment: i have cancelled the current build which i uploaded for review and now the status is "developer rejected"

but i am not getting transfer option link

i have logged into itunesconnect with admin user

Comment: Yes, its your first build and no any past builds were in Ready for Sale status, so you won't get App Transfer option.

Comment: Now, you have to first delete app, application identifier from existing apple account and you have to create same application and application identifier in new account and upload it there.

Comment: No one build i.e 1.0.3 is in apple store(Status is ready for sale)
and the one which i cancelled is 1.0.4

Comment: Ok, so you can transfer your 1.0.3 to new account and then you can upload new build 1.0.4 there.

Comment: do i need to login with account holder(Role) credentials ? Currently i have logged in as admin(Role) user and i am  not getting that option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193673/discussion-between-bhavik-modi-and-sunilkumar-godi).

Comment: I am able to see link when i login with account holder credentials